# Spring Security deprecated @AuthenticationPrincipal

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, deprecated

As you know @AuthenticationPrincipal in  web.bind.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal is depreacted . It is recommended to use core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal.
So we have changed import statements as core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal and now we are getting below error :

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.xxx.xxx.authentication.OurUserDetailsImpl]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.xxx.xxx.authentication.OurUserDetailsImpl.<init>()
```

Are there any known problem related with this annotation ?
P.S we are using parameterized constructor and we dont have a default constructor so I am aware of this. 
Many thanks.

Comment: What version of Spring Security are you using? Does it work with the deprecated `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation? How are you adding AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver? Did you ensure that `org.springframework.security.web.method.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver` is being used vs `org.springframework.security.web.bind.support.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver`

Comment: Yes it works with deprecated annotation. Spring Security version is 4.0.3 and we didnt add AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver yet. As soon as We add it I will share the result . Thanks

Comment: Great ! It works now thanks for your support.

Comment: Glad I could help. Is there a reason you feel that you missed this (i.e. do we need to make this obvious in documentation in a spot or multiple spots we missed?)

Comment: @RobWinch how do you add `AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver` when using annotation-based configuration? It seems I need to tell `spring-webmvc` to use it in my rest app, but it doesn't and just ignores `spring-security` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54352315/spring-security-authenticates-and-creates-principal-but-controller-gets-differen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are using `org.springframework.security.web.method.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipalArgum‌​entResolver` as apposed to `org.springframework.security.web.bind.support.AuthenticationPrincipalArgum‌​entResolver`.

**UPDATE** I created [#3771](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3771) to track making this easier to follow in the documentation.